# How can we map timestamp with timezone type oracle db column with projection classes in java?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, oracle12c

```
Exception:Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101at     org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:71)at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103)at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:741)
```

Code snippet:

```
@Query(value = "select id, age, name, creationDate FROM Person WHERE age=?1", nativeQuery=true)List<PersonView> getPersonsByAge(int age);
```

and interface:

```
public interface PersonView {Long getId();Integer getAge();String getName();OffsetDateTime getCreationDate();}
```

Table description:

```
Name            Null?     Type
id              NOT NULL  NUMBER
age                       NUMBER
name                      VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)
creation_date   NOT NULL  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

I have tried with setting OffsetDateTime to ZonedDateTime, Timestamp, String but no luck.